# When I try to "catkin build" I get error messages

Tags: ros, catkin, ros-kinetic, ubuntu, vrep

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am using Ubuntu 16.04 64-bit.V-REP 3.5.0 64 bit.ROS Kinetic desktop full, joystick and brics actuator packages. When I try to "catkin build" under my ROS ws I receive following error messages. How can I sort them out?

```
CMake Error at /opt/ros/kinetic/share/catkin/cmake/catkinConfig.cmake:83 (find_package):
  Could not find a package configuration file provided by "joy" with any of
  the following names:

    joyConfig.cmake
    joy-config.cmake

 Add the installation prefix of "joy" to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH or set... 

...

Failed     << vrep_joy:cmake                       
                  [ Exited with code 1 ]
Failed    <<< vrep_joy                             
                   [ 3.8 seconds ]
Abandoned <<< vrep_teleop                          
                       [ Unrelated job failed ]
Abandoned <<< vrepscan_to_laserscan                
                       [ Unrelated job failed ]
Finished  <<< vrep_common                          
                   [ 6.5 seconds ]
[build] Summary: 3 of 6 packages succeeded.
[build]   Ignored:   None.           
[build]   Warnings:  None.           
[build]   Abandoned: 2 packages were abandoned.
[build]   Failed:    1 packages failed.
[build] Runtime: 7.0 seconds total.
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/315813/when-i-try-to-%22catkin-build%22-i-get-error-messages/) by [acikbasm](https://answers.ros.org/users/40010/acikbasm/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2019-02-16

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2019-02-17**:
You're not showing actual errors, just the summary output of `catkin_tools` that tells us *something* failed to compile.

**Comment by [acikbasm](https://answers.ros.org/users/40010/acikbasm/) on 2019-02-17**:
Maybe expression was not good enough but anyway at some further step at my processes I needed them have installed all correctly. To re-ask the question in another way; how to complete that compilation then?

**Comment by [acikbasm](https://answers.ros.org/users/40010/acikbasm/) on 2019-02-17**:
CMake Error at /opt/ros/kinetic/share/catkin/cmake/catkinConfig.cmake:83 (find_package):
Could not find a package configuration file provided by "joy" with any of
the following names:

```
joyConfig.cmake
joy-config.cmake
```

Add the installation prefix of "joy" to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH or set...

**Comment by [acikbasm](https://answers.ros.org/users/40010/acikbasm/) on 2019-02-17**:
I think above message is the error message.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2019-02-18**:
It would appear you have not installed all dependencies prior to starting the build.

Please refer to #q252478 for the general workflow when attempting to build pkgs from sources.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

`sudo apt-get install ros-kinetic-joy` should solve your problem and then source your workspace again.

---

Originally posted by [kosmastsk](https://answers.ros.org/users/36854/kosmastsk/) with karma: 210 on 2019-02-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [acikbasm](https://answers.ros.org/users/40010/acikbasm/) on 2019-02-18**:
when I do it I get another set of error messages as below...
E: Encountered a section with no Package: header
E: Problem with MergeList /var/lib/apt/lists/packages.ros.org_ros_ubuntu_dists_xenial_main_binary-amd64_Packages

**Comment by [kosmastsk](https://answers.ros.org/users/36854/kosmastsk/) on 2019-02-18**:
Try to remove the existing Merge List with `sudo rm -vf /var/lib/apt/lists/*` and then create a new one with `sudo apt-get update`
[source](https://askubuntu.com/questions/30072/how-do-i-fix-a-problem-with-mergelist-or-status-file-could-not-be-parsed-err)

**Comment by [acikbasm](https://answers.ros.org/users/40010/acikbasm/) on 2019-02-18**:
Thanks that worked well. Now only 1 minor issue the rest of the installation was completed...

**Comment by [kosmastsk](https://answers.ros.org/users/36854/kosmastsk/) on 2019-02-18**:
You can mark this question as solved and open a new question, if needed, for your installation ;)

**Comment by [acikbasm](https://answers.ros.org/users/40010/acikbasm/) on 2019-02-18**:
Now I have one remaining issue apart from that in case you know;
I try to run a robot simulation in V-rep at ubuntu 16.04. First I type roscore, then I initialize V-rep, and then I open a simple simulation code which is in *.ttt file. Afterall, I type command "roslaunch vrep_apps base.launch" but...

**Comment by [acikbasm](https://answers.ros.org/users/40010/acikbasm/) on 2019-02-18**:
I get another error message:
[base.launch] is neither a launch file in package [vrep_apps] nor is [vrep_apps] a launch file name
The traceback for the exception was written to the log file.

**Comment by [acikbasm](https://answers.ros.org/users/40010/acikbasm/) on 2019-02-18**:
Any idea about this issue?